# Configuring a Jetty application with env variables

Tags: configuration, jetty

I'm trying to deploy a Java WAR file in Jetty 9 with Docker. I would like to configure things as database URI string, loglevel and such via environment variables - so that I could also use the link features of Docker.

But, if I start the application via `java -jar start.jar`, the environment variables I've set are not available to the application.

What is the simplest way to pass environment variables to my application?

Comment: Can you use properties instead? (as in system properties `-Dkey=val`, or properties files)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find a solution for Jetty.
Just set `JAVA_OPTIONS` in the Dockerfile and you should be good to go.

The full Dockerfile as for my case looks like this:

```
FROM jetty:9.2.10
MAINTAINER Me "me@me.com"
ENV spring.profiles.active=dev
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dkey=value"
ADD myWar.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT.war
```

Answer (score 1):

Using system environment variables (aka [`System.getenv(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String))) is not supported by Jetty's `start.jar`

Feel free to file a feature request with Jetty for that support.

Know however, that the Jetty `start.jar` process does support properties, either as System properties, or as start properties.  Either on the command line or in the `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

Comment: I'm trying with properties this: ```System.getProperties().contains("dbhost")``` - but neither adding ```dbhost="localhost"``` nor ```-Ddbhost="localhost"``` to the start.ini file works